# finding in numpy pair values (without zeros) and get the keys

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose that I have a numpy like this

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1373, 1371, 1365, 1371, 1375],
         [0, 0, 0, 1388, 1371, 1365, 1301, 1302]])
```

I have to find all value pairs (compare idx 0 == 1).
for example:

```
pairs = (a[0] == a[1])
# [ True  True  True False  True True False False]
```

but now, I'd like to have the idx's as result without comparing the zero values.
for example:

```
[4, 5]
```

This is an example, in my case I have around 100k datapoints. I'd like to find an efficient way.

Comment: How would you form the pairs? What's the shape of `a` in your actual use case?

Comment: In the real case, I receive LIDAR data. Each row has a different angle (LIDAR sensor swings from 0 degree to 50 degree). Each row has 360 data points (distance measurement). In this case I compare 0.1-> 0.2 degree (row1 -> row2). With the answer below, I find collisions resp. obstacles.
To answer your question: origin: `np.zeros((len(**received data**), 360), dtype=np.int)` for each row...

Comment: Are you doing these comparisons/operations between first two rows only? If not, how are you doing those comparisons across other rows and also consider adding a bit more representative sample?

Comment: ahh, sorry, no I do this comparisons for every row. In my case around 200 every second. I would iterate through the rows, but if you know a better solution let me know! But in my point of view, this would be a new question. I'm happy with the proposed solution.

Comment: I guess you could cook up a new question stating that you are looking to vectorize and add in the iterative solution which could be used as a reference to verify results, etc.

Comment: actually a good idea, I will do that tomorrow and make a link to this question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [14]: result = [r[0] for r in np.argwhere(a[0,:] == a[1,:]) if a[0, r] != 0]

In [15]: result
Out[15]: [4, 5]
```